# SYNOLOGY DS718+ NAS disk as shared folder for 30 people

Tags: hard-disk, networking, nas

In our office we use as a shared folder (we are 30 users). This older exists in a local server `Windows Server 2008 R2`. The problem is that the free disk space of our server is getting very low, so I thought to get an NAS disk.

After some search, I ended to these devices:

- [SYNOLOGY DS718+](https://www.synology.com/en-global/products/DS718+) and
- [WD Red PRO NAS 4TB](https://www.wdc.com/products/business-internal-storage/wd-red-pro.html#WD4002FFWX) (2 of them in raid 1)

Is this combination a good recommendation for us?

Our network is built with gigabit switches and UTP cables of Cat 5e and 6 and
I can plug in 2 utp cables in the DS718+. Our files are mostly MS office files, PDFs, and image files (from Adobe Photoshop, illustrator)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you using SMB to share? What's your budget? Do you care about expandability? Power consumption?

Comment: Budget = 1000 Euros, 4TB is enough, don't care about power consumption

Comment: Upgradability? Is used hardware okay?

Comment: I don't know what is `SMB` so I don't think I am using it! Yes, the current hardware configuration is ok.

Comment: By used I mean pre-owned (specifically older servers.) SMB is probably the most common file sharing protocol (especially on Windows.) If you don't know, you're probably using that or FTP.

Comment: If i remember well, I had done right click -> Properties ->Sharing  on the folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73070/discussion-between-jmy1000-and-yaylitzis).